# Is it possible to detect domain provider from a URL?

Tags: dns, service-provider

If I am given a URL `http://example.com/` is there a way (API or otherwise) for me to find out which domain provider the URL is associated with? I'm trying to write code cases for different domain providers depending on results.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) query, you can find out the registrar who registered the domain with the registry operators. Have a look at the [WHOIS for the domain thisisatest.com](http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=thisisatest.com&type=domain). There are several APIs available which also allow you to do that programmatically.

However, assuming that you are looking for the name of the hosting company that the domain owner actually bought the domain from, this will not get you very far. There are multiple levels of reselling within the domain name registrar system. Smaller registrars pay larger registrars which in turn pay the registry operators.

That means, using a WHOIS query, you will always only be able to get the name of the last company in this chain. To my knowledge, there is no publicly accessible way to find out the names of the other companies that have resold the domain.